# Getting contact notes with garethp/php-ews

Tags: php, exchangewebservices, php-ews

I'm using garethp/php-ews to import Exchange Contacts to a MySQL Database and export them into another Exchange Account.

Everything works fine so far, but I'm not able to get the notes from the contacts.

`$contact->getNotes()` doesn't work, `$contact->getBody()`  doesn't work either.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 0):

Ok, got it.

You get the notes by using `getBody()`. But this works only, if you get **one** contact object by using `getItem()` or `getContact()` and **not** if you load a whole bunch by using `getContacts()`.